# passing a type of a struct c++

Tags: c++, struct

I want to pass a type of a struct to a function, which then will cycle through a vector of these structs to check a condition. Is this anyhow possible?

```
#define EMPTY -1
struct CHAMPION{
    int champ_ID;
    int weaponL_ID;
    int weaponR_ID;
}

vector<string> Champions;

int getChampIndex("struct_obj" obj, int value){
    for(int i=0; i<Champions.size(); i++){
        if(Champions[i].obj == value){return i;}
    }
}

int main(){
    //fill Champions vector

    SearchedChamp = getChampIndex(champ_ID, 17);
    //process SearchedChamp

    NoWeaponL = getChampIndex(weaponL_ID, EMPTY);
    //process NoWeaponL

    NoWeaponR = getChampIndex(weaponR_ID, EMPTY);
    //process NoWeaponR

}
```

Comment: Search for questions on finding elements in a vector.

Comment: The (pseudo)code provided doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The question is very poorly written. But, it seems that you are trying to access individual members of a struct. If so, there is a way.

Comment: I just want to either cycle through Champions[i].champID or Champions[i].weaponL_id or Champions[i].weaponR_id in the same function without writing the code 3 time

Comment: Field names cannot be passed to function parameters like the pseudo code shows. You will have to resort to C macro tricks or lookup tables to access field values by runtime-specified names

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with fields. I'm not sure if you can bind instance functions using a placeholder for the first argument (the object). If so, you could use a "class-wise bound" `std::function<int(void)>` as the first argument for your `getChampIndex`, bind it to your struct's value getters (yes, this approach requires `int get_champID()` etc.) and invoke it consecutively with all members of your champions list, passing the actual champion instance as the first parameter. 
This should at least require C++11 (not sure what got in when, I've been coding with C++14 for the last few months), plus, it is horrible design with respect to readability and robustness. And if you need this, it's definitely a code smell of serious design errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the `vector<string> Champions` is a `vector<CHAMPION>` because otherwise the whole `getChampIndex` doesn't make sense.

You can use a pointer to member to pass the member to `getChampIndex`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

static constexpr int EMPTY = -1;

struct CHAMPION{
    int champ_ID;
    int weaponL_ID;
    int weaponR_ID;
};

typedef int CHAMPION::*FieldPointer;

std::vector<CHAMPION> Champions;

std::vector<CHAMPION>::size_type getChampIndex(FieldPointer field, int value){
    auto const i = std::find_if( Champions.begin(), Champions.end(), [&](auto const& c) {return (c.*field) == value;} );

    // what do we do if there is no element with searched value?
    return i - Champions.begin();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        //fill Champions vector

    auto SearchedChamp = getChampIndex(&CHAMPION::champ_ID, 17);
    //process SearchedChamp

    auto NoWeaponL = getChampIndex(&CHAMPION::weaponL_ID, EMPTY);
    //process NoWeaponL

    auto NoWeaponR = getChampIndex(&CHAMPION::weaponR_ID, EMPTY);
    //process NoWeaponR
}
```

I think the design of the struct itself is not very well suited, but this is hard to judge from the problem description. If you have to stick with the design, I would probably not use this technique and just go with lambda functions:

```
template<typename Predicate>
std::vector<CHAMPION>::size_type getChampIndex(Predicate pred){
    auto const i = std::find_if( Champions.begin(), Champions.end(), pred );
    return i - Champions.begin();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        //fill Champions vector

    auto SearchedChamp = getChampIndex([](CHAMPION const& c) {return c.champ_ID == 17; } );
    //process SearchedChamp

    auto NoWeaponL = getChampIndex([](CHAMPION const& c) {return c.weaponL_ID == EMPTY;} );
    //process NoWeaponL

    auto NoWeaponR = getChampIndex([](CHAMPION const& c) {return c.weaponR_ID == EMPTY;});
    //process NoWeaponR
}
```